# Septic Shock: I'll kill myself before you kill me

Tags: evolution, immunology, infection

Most of the deaths caused by extracellular bacteria don't actually result directly form their action. Rather, it results from an overreaction of the immune system to antigens such as LPS and LTA (Superantigens are bacterial toxins with an enormous power in originating immune responses; they are able to activate numerous T cells through a different TCR, which will produce too many pro-inflammatory cytokines, resulting in an excessive reaction by the body and causing self-tissue damage, etc), and it is this excessive reaction of the immune system which ends up killing the organism.

http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/311549.php
http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/305782.php?sr

How come, after all this evolutionary time, we have this self-killing mechanism? Why do T-cells have receptors to such generalized and potent antigens, which will frequently result in self-damage? Is it because at the point of infection that this happens, we would die anyway from it, so it doesn't alter fitness?

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Can you please support your claim that `Most of the deaths caused by extracellular bacteria [..] results from an overreaction of the immune system to antigens` with a reference?

Comment: @Remi.b sure, I think it is all very clear here: http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/311549.php
also here: http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/305782.php?sr

Comment: @Remi.b this is also interesting: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4422540/

Comment: the mechanism exists to protect against the spread of infections, the infection cannot utilize the cells to make more copies of themselves if the cells suicide when infected, this is a perfectly normal response to low level infections, sore throats for instance are often caused by this response. Additionally animals that reach the point of septic shock (massive widespread infections) would rarely survive anyway. so the question you should ask is without any form of medical intervention is the individual actually less likely to survive without this response.

Comment: @John the question is somewhat that, is there a chance that organisms who died from septic shock would have survived if the immune reaction was less strong? because if yes then it would make sense that we had evolved in that direction.

Comment: @John in this case I was talking specifically of extracellular bacteria, which don't grow and reproduce inside host cells, so the death of host cells to prevent that wouln't fit here

Comment: Ignore most of my statment, I was thinking of a different antigen response then you are talking about. Although I should mention none of your sources indicate percentages of extra to intracellular infection in sepsis. As for septic shock survival the question is whether MORE would survive, because weakening the immune response is going to get some killed. Almost everything in biology is a cost benefit trade off. this paper has a good description of the benefit of various immune responses during sepsis. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4422540/

Comment: This excerpt is also relevent.  http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/Documents/college-mds/facilities/cis/Essentialimmunology/Chapter1.pdf  "Mice deficient in tumour
necrosis factor are protected fromshock induced by lipopolysaccharide but on the other hand are
more likely to die from overwhelming bacterial sepsis. This illustrates the fine line that the immune
system has to tread between evoking protective immunity and killing the host."

Comment: @John yes, but knocking out TNF is an extreme deficiency in the immune system. I was thinking more of something like the organism being able to detect when the immune response is causing too much, potentially fatal host damaged, and then downregulating it a bit

Comment: @John yes, the question should then be if having that mechanism would pay off, meaning less individuals would die from weakened immune response than from an excessive one.

Comment: which is an entire new system (which could also be exploited) for an exceedingly rare circumstance. Remember the rarer the event the less evolution will be able to prepare for it becasue it is overpowered by more common selective pressures.

Comment: @John true, although I doubt apart from modern times that it was of such rarity

Comment: Which shows how well the current setup works, consider people prior to the invention antibiotics and germ theory, people routinely lost limbs and survived so the existing system obviously works for preventing sepsis. The only time septic shock comes into play is under circumstances people were unlikely to survive in the first place, severe sepsis. You can see how fast response is more important than a measured response. Preventing severe sepsis would be more important than mitigating it under natural conditions.

Comment: @John but not to the point of killing itself. I imagine there must have been a lot of deaths from septic shock caused by, say, a severe urinary infection, whereas if the response were more contained maybe they would have survived

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57779/discussion-between-filipe-rocha-and-john).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The important thing to recognize about the host response to sepsis is that it is actually a generalization of mechanisms used in local infection response by the innate immune system. When an animal has a local infection, such as at a wound site, innate immune cells such as monocytes and macrophages recognize 'generic' bacterial features, such as lipopolysaccharide (LPS). When they recognize these features, they respond by engulfing the pathogen and releasing cytokines that result in local vasodilation and inflammation. In this context, these responses are close to ideal. Vasodilation helps to isolate the area and promotes the recruitment of more immune cells.

These sorts of small infections are very common for all animals (just about every creature cuts itself at least once), including humans, and the absence of this response would result in sepsis (not the immune response, but just sepsis itself) because the infection would not be contained. Control of such local infections is thus 'life-or-death' for all creatures—which is an extremely powerful selective pressure.

The other thing to consider here is when in nature are these local defences overwhelmed such that sepsis, and then septic shock, which is what you are asking about, occurs. The answer is that it does not happen very often. Transient bacteremia is relatively common (it even happens when you brush your teeth, see [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2746717/) paper for example), but overwhelming bacteremia, sepsis, is not very common in healthy individuals. It is generally a condition that affects weakened individuals and those who have already reproduced. We notice it far more now because it is a major cause of death for humans hospitalized for other conditions, as well as older people with pneumonia. Most of the primary causes of sepsis though—major wounds, pneumonia, weakened immune systems—would be death sentences in themselves in the absence of medicine, irrespective of the organism's response to the sepsis.

That is not to say it is completely invisible to selection, for example [this paper](http://www.cell.com/immunity/abstract/S1074-7613(15)00076-X), and others like it, demonstrate that the immune cells responsible for septic shock are regulated by hypoxia (a major feature of shock). However, it is reasonable to say that any fitness advantage conveyed by a reduction in the intensity of septic shock would be dwarfed by the fitness penalty paid if that reduction also reduced the efficiency of the response to local infections. For this reason, it is likely that septic shock is an evolutionary accident, a trait that exists in part because it is irrevocably linked to a set of highly advantageous traits (those involved in local infection response), rather than a trait that has been extensively selected on by evolution.

Note that this answer is my opinion only. To the best of my knowledge, there is no definitive answer to this question yet, and future research may prove me wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Seems like you are quite familier with how ideal answers are posted here ;) +1 for the effort, and this comment, just to appreciate the nice content in your first answer! :D